# Putting a lock screen photo on a Windows 8 computer

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

I disabled the lock screen on my Widows 8 laptop. Is there a way to put the lock screen photo back on, or do I have to stick with how it is?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Registry to **HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization** and set the value **NoLockScreen** to **0**. After a reboot the Lockscreen is back and you can customize it again in the settings.